# Data getting lost between 2 ViewDidLoad calls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Inside a UIViewController class, I have a tableView who gets called like this by clicking on a navBar button:

```
-(IBAction) addButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    CreateQuestionController *createQuestionViewController = [[CreateQuestionController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateQuestionController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:createQuestionViewController animated:YES];
    [createQuestionViewController release];
}
```

This method gets called nowhere else in my code. Well, when I click this navBar button and the view shows up I find out that the ViewDidLoad method gets called twice (which is normal in this case) BUT the data I enter here gets lost. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    textView.text=@"Type your question here";
    NSLog(@"Question text:%@", textView.text);
}
```

Log:

```
2011-07-11 10:56:35.727 HelpMe[1343:207] Question text:Type your question here
2011-07-11 10:56:35.728 HelpMe[1343:207] Question text:(null)
```

What's going on?
Thank you

**Edit:**
Other symptoms:
- Cannot push another view
- Cannot change the image of a button

Comment: no memory warnings, I added a NSLog inside - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: I'd suggest setting a breakpoint to see where the second call comes from.

Comment: Did you set the view property of you view controller.

Comment: @dasdom: I did set the View property. @omz: I tried to put a breakpoint inside ViewDidLoad, but cannot figure out what calls it the second time. First time it gets called, ok, then a bunch of assembly commands and it executes again ViewDidLoad. Am I setting the breakpoint at the wrong place?

Comment: Did you override the `initWithNibName:` method in `CreateQuestionController`? If so, can you post the code?

Comment: @pgb: no I didn't overwrite it

Comment: Did you rule out `addButtonPressed:` being called more than once?

Comment: @pgb: We figured out why the method is getting called twice. It's because my nib's got more than one view. It doesn't explain the real problem which is the data loss

Comment: Even if there are several views in the nib, viewDidLoad should be called once. But anyway, if addButtonPressed: is somehow called twice, you'll see weird problems because it'll try to play two animations at once (in pushViewController: animated:).

Comment: @SVD: addButtonPressed is called only once. So that's not the reason viewDidLoad is getting called twice.

Comment: thanks everyone, problem solved. My nib file organization was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in my nib file. I deleted my controller and assigned all my outlets to the File's owner